# Why SP gives slightly different result than SELECT statement with same filters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, exists

Cant understand why Stored Procedure gives slightly different result than `SELECT` statement. In the SP I filter my data in `#TempTable` then using EXISTS statement.
And in my `SELECT` query same values in `WHERE` clause. 
I tried one by one parameters and only `SICCode` effecting the result.

Here is my SP:

```
     ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[EarningPlazaCommercial] 
@State varchar(50),
@StartDate datetime,
@EndDate datetime,
@AsOfDate datetime,
@SICCode nvarchar(max),
@Coverage varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
    CREATE TABLE #PolicyNumbers  (PolicyNumber varchar(50))
    INSERT INTO #PolicyNumbers SELECT   PolicyNumber 
                                FROM    PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet 
                                WHERE SICCode IN (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable](@SICCode,','))
                                AND State IN (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable](@State,','))  
                                AND Coverage IN (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable](@Coverage,','))
    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_C_PolicyNumbers_PolicyNumber ON #PolicyNumbers(PolicyNumber) 
    ; WITH Earned_to_date AS (
       SELECT CAST(@AsOfDate AS DATE) AS Earned_to_date
    ), policy_data AS (
            SELECT 
            PolicyNumber,
            --Coverage
           Cast(PolicyEffectiveDate AS DATE) AS PolicyEffectiveDate
    ,       Cast(PolicyExpirationDate AS DATE) AS PolicyExpirationDate
    ,       WrittenPremium
    --,     --State
            FROM PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet piwp
            WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT PolicyNumber FROM #PolicyNumbers pn WHERE pn.PolicyNumber = piwp.PolicyNumber)   
    )

    , digits AS (
    SELECT digit
       FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4)
    ,      (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) AS z2 (digit)
    ), numbers AS (
    SELECT 1000 * d4.digit + 100 * d3.digit + 10 * d2.digit + d1.digit AS number
        FROM digits AS d1
        CROSS JOIN digits AS d2
        CROSS JOIN digits AS d3
        CROSS JOIN digits AS d4
    ), calendar AS (
    SELECT
        DateAdd(month, number, '1753-01-01') AS month_of
    ,   DateAdd(month, number, '1753-02-01') AS month_after
        FROM numbers
    ), policy_dates AS (
    SELECT
       PolicyNumber
    ,   CASE
            WHEN month_of < PolicyEffectiveDate THEN PolicyEffectiveDate
            ELSE month_of
        END AS StartRiskMonth
    ,   CASE
           WHEN PolicyExpirationDate < month_after THEN PolicyExpirationDate
           WHEN Earned_to_date.Earned_to_date < month_after THEN Earned_to_date
           ELSE month_after
        END AS EndRiskMonth
    ,   DateDiff(day, PolicyEffectiveDate, PolicyExpirationDate) AS policy_days
    ,   WrittenPremium
        FROM policy_data
        JOIN calendar
            ON (policy_data.PolicyEffectiveDate < calendar.month_after
            AND calendar.month_of < policy_data.PolicyExpirationDate)
        CROSS JOIN Earned_to_date
        WHERE  month_of < Earned_to_date
    )
    SELECT      
                Year(StartRiskMonth) as YearStartRisk, 
                Month(StartRiskMonth) as MonthStartRisk,
                c.YearNum,c.MonthNum,
                convert(varchar(7), StartRiskMonth, 120) as RiskMonth,
                sum(WrittenPremium * DateDiff(day, StartRiskMonth, EndRiskMonth) / policy_days) as EarnedPremium
    FROM        tblCalendar  c
    LEFT  JOIN policy_dates l ON c.YearNum=Year(l.StartRiskMonth) and c.MonthNum = Month(l.StartRiskMonth) AND l.StartRiskMonth BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    WHERE c.YearNum Not IN (2017) 
    GROUP BY    convert(varchar(7), StartRiskMonth, 120),
                Year(StartRiskMonth) , Month(StartRiskMonth),
                c.YearNum,c.MonthNum
    ORDER BY    c.YearNum,c.MonthNum
    DROP TABLE  #PolicyNumbers
```

END
Then I execute it:

```
EXEC [dbo].[EarningPlazaCommercial] @State='CA,NV,AZ', 
                                    @StartDate = '01-01-2015',
                                    @EndDate = '10-31-2016',
                                    @AsOfDate = '11-30-2016',
                                    @SICCode = '0161,0173,0179,0181,0191,0722,0752,0761,0782,1440,1441,1442,1521,1522,161,1611,1629,1711,172,1731,1742',
                                    @Coverage = 'Uninsured,Medical,Physical Damage,Premises,Terrorism,Underinsured,Liability'
```

And here is my `SELECT` query:

```
 ; WITH Earned_to_date AS (
   SELECT Cast('11-30-2016' AS DATE) AS Earned_to_date
), policy_data AS (
    SELECT
        PolicyNumber
,       Cast(PolicyEffectiveDate AS DATE) AS PolicyEffectiveDate
,       Cast(PolicyExpirationDate AS DATE) AS PolicyExpirationDate
,       WrittenPremium
        FROM PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet
        WHERE State IN ('CA','AZ','NV') 
        AND SICCode IN ('0161','0173','0179','0181','0191','0722','0752','0761','0782','1440','1441','1442','1521','1522','161','1611','1629','1711','172','1731','1742')
        AND Coverage IN ('Uninsured','Medical','Physical Damage','Premises','Terrorism','Underinsured','Liability')
)

, digits AS (
SELECT digit
   FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4)
,      (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) AS z2 (digit)
), numbers AS (
SELECT 1000 * d4.digit + 100 * d3.digit + 10 * d2.digit + d1.digit AS number
    FROM digits AS d1
    CROSS JOIN digits AS d2
    CROSS JOIN digits AS d3
    CROSS JOIN digits AS d4
), calendar AS (
SELECT
    DateAdd(month, number, '1753-01-01') AS month_of
,   DateAdd(month, number, '1753-02-01') AS month_after
    FROM numbers
), policy_dates AS (
SELECT
   PolicyNumber
,   CASE
        WHEN month_of < PolicyEffectiveDate THEN PolicyEffectiveDate
        ELSE month_of
    END AS StartRiskMonth
,   CASE
       WHEN PolicyExpirationDate < month_after THEN PolicyExpirationDate
       WHEN Earned_to_date.Earned_to_date < month_after THEN Earned_to_date
       ELSE month_after
    END AS EndRiskMonth
,   DateDiff(day, PolicyEffectiveDate, PolicyExpirationDate) AS policy_days
,   WrittenPremium
    FROM policy_data
    JOIN calendar
        ON (policy_data.PolicyEffectiveDate < calendar.month_after
        AND calendar.month_of < policy_data.PolicyExpirationDate)
    CROSS JOIN Earned_to_date
    WHERE  month_of < Earned_to_date
)
SELECT  
            Year(StartRiskMonth) as YearStartRisk, 
            Month(StartRiskMonth) as MonthStartRisk,
            c.YearNum,c.MonthNum,
            convert(varchar(7), StartRiskMonth, 120) as RiskMonth,
            sum(WrittenPremium * DateDiff(day, StartRiskMonth, EndRiskMonth) / policy_days) as EarnedPremium
FROM        tblCalendar  c
LEFT  JOIN policy_dates l ON c.YearNum=Year(l.StartRiskMonth) and c.MonthNum = Month(l.StartRiskMonth) and l.StartRiskMonth BETWEEN '01-01-2015' AND '10-31-2016'
WHERE c.YearNum Not IN (2017) 
GROUP BY    convert(varchar(7), StartRiskMonth, 120),
            Year(StartRiskMonth) , Month(StartRiskMonth),
            c.YearNum,c.MonthNum
ORDER BY    c.YearNum,c.MonthNum
```

What am I missing here?
This is the split function `StringOfStringsToTable`

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable]
    (
        @Strings varchar(8000),
        @Separator char(1)
    )
RETURNS @StringTable table (String varchar(500))
AS
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @String varchar(500), @Pos int

        SET @Strings = LTRIM(RTRIM(@Strings))+ @Separator
        SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(@Separator, @Strings, 1)

            WHILE @Pos > 0
            BEGIN
                SET @String = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@Strings, @Pos - 1)))

                IF @String <> '' INSERT INTO @StringTable VALUES (@String)

                SET @Strings = RIGHT(@Strings, LEN(@Strings) - @Pos)
                SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(@Separator, @Strings, 1)
            END

    RETURN
    END
```

This is the result from SP:
[image]

And this one is the result from SELECT query:

[image]

This is how `policy_data` result looks like

[image]

Comment: Without some sample data and an explanation of what is different it is impossible for us to say. Let's start here. StringOfStringsToTable Is that a splitter function? can you share the code for it? Maybe that doesn't return exactly what you think it should.

Comment: Thanks. Added some samples.

Comment: Ugh. Of all the splitters out there the looping ones are the worst. Here are several much better options. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: Can you at least provide the actual queries? All you have posted is the list of ctes. We can't even see the final query in either the procedure or your ad hoc query.

Comment: Updated to full SP and full SELECT statement

Comment: Splitters works fine. The only parameter that changing the result is `@SICCode`. And I cant understand why

Comment: No offense mate but that splitter is the worst. It is using a loop and is a multi statement table valued function. For small lists it is acceptable but for any list that even resembles being long the performance is going to go down the toilet. As for the issue at hand I can't see what is causing the difference but those two queries are pretty different from each other in a number of ways. Without tables and sample data to recreate this it is just way too much effort to debug this.

Comment: Could the policy_data query return duplicates? If so there will be a difference between just joining the data and doing the "if exists"

Comment: You might be right. I added a sample of what policy_data returns above.

Comment: So, were you correct? Is that what causes the problem?

Comment: #Sean,#James  there are more details about the issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40942596/how-would-be-the-right-way-to-use-exists-clause