# How would be the right way to use EXISTS clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, exists

In my SP I am creating a temp table  `#PolicyNumbers` and populating it with `Policy Numbers` based on the parameters that will be supplied to the SP.

```
CREATE TABLE #PolicyNumbers  (PolicyNumber varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #PolicyNumbers SELECT   PolicyNumber
                            FROM    PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet 
                            WHERE   State IN (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable](@State,','))  
                            AND Coverage IN (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable](@Coverage,','))
                            AND SICCode IN (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[StringOfStringsToTable](@SICCode,','))
```

Further below in my SP I'm using `EXISTS` statement to filter only those 
`PolicyNumber`s that been selected based on parameters.

```
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT PolicyNumber FROM #PolicyNumbers pn WHERE pn.PolicyNumber = piwp.PolicyNumber)
```

So the result from `#PolicyNumbers` DOES contain duplicates PolicyNumbers:

[image]

Then furthure in my SP I have `SELECT` statement and the result also contains duplicate `PolicyNumber`s:

```
SELECT 
            PolicyNumber,
            Cast(PolicyEffectiveDate AS DATE) AS PolicyEffectiveDate,
            Cast(PolicyExpirationDate AS DATE) AS PolicyExpirationDate,
            WrittenPremium
            FROM PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet
```

[image]

And now I am using `EXIST` statement:

```
SELECT 
        PolicyNumber,
        Cast(PolicyEffectiveDate AS DATE) AS PolicyEffectiveDate,
        Cast(PolicyExpirationDate AS DATE) AS PolicyExpirationDate,
        WrittenPremium
        FROM PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet piwp
        WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT PolicyNumber FROM #PolicyNumbers pn WHERE pn.PolicyNumber = piwp.PolicyNumber)
```

Is everything correct so far?
If yes, then why do I have slightly different result using `SELECT` statement and passing same parameters in `WHERE` clause using IN (@MyParameter)?

```
SELECT 
            PolicyNumber,
            Cast(PolicyEffectiveDate AS DATE) AS PolicyEffectiveDate,
            Cast(PolicyExpirationDate AS DATE) AS PolicyExpirationDate,
            WrittenPremium
            FROM PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet piwp
            WHERE    State IN (@State) 
                    AND SICCode IN (@SICCode)
                    AND Coverage IN (@Coverage)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between your two queries, is that the first gets a list of policy numbers where at least one of the rows in the table matches on `State`, `SICode` and `Coverage`. Since there are multiple rows in `PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet` and each can have different `State`, `SICode` and `Coverage` (presumably), this is not the same as selecting only rows from `PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet` that match on those three predicates.

Here is a simplified example:

```
Create Table PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet  (
    PolicyNumber varchar(1),
    State varchar(3))

Insert Into PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet 
Values  ('A', 'Qld'),
        ('A', 'NSW');

Create Table #PolicyNumbers (PolicyNumber char(1));
Insert Into #PolicyNumbers
Select PolicyNumber
  From PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet 
  Where State = 'Qld';

-- Returns all policy numbers where at least one row matches the predicate.
Select *
  From PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet As piwp
  Where Exists (Select 1 From #PolicyNumbers As pn
                Where pn.PolicyNumber = piwp.PolicyNumber);

-- Returns only rows of 'A' that match the filter predicate                    
Select *
  From PlazaInsuranceWPDataSet 
  Where State = 'Qld';
```

One (and only one) of the rows of policy number 'A' matches the condition so when we write down that policy number in our temp table and then compare to it later we'll get all rows of 'A' back.

Comment: #Mendosi 
Thank you. Awesome explanation. And thanks for the example. Its really good to know that.
It just leads me to another question, which way would be correct? Or I should say more appropriate? Or it depends on the objective? The goal is to choose the policy numbers based on parameters and then calculate earnings for those policies. I want to work with policies that only have particular SICCode, State and Coverage. So I'd assume that using `#PolicyNumbers` and `EXISTS` would be the correct way. Am I right?

Comment: It sounds like the `EXISTS` version would be correct for you to answer that question.